# Matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue with multiplicity $>1$, is $A$ diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue with multiplicity $>1$,  is $A$ diagonalisable?

I know that if $A$ has distinct eigenvalues $\Rightarrow$ all eigenvectors are linearly independent $\Rightarrow$ I can find an inverable $P$ s.t. $P^{-1}AP=D$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with my distinct eigenvalues

Comment: The answer is, it depends. Just check $\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ (which is diagonalizable) and $\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ (which is not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For example

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
has the eigenvalue with multiplicity $2$ but it isn't diagonalizable.

**Notice** A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the multiplicity of every eigenvalue equals to the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace.

Comment: Not diagonalisable because I only get 1 vector and not 2? I got $(1,0)^T$

Comment: If this matrix is diagonalizable then it would be similar to $I_2$ but in this case this matrix equals to $I_2$ which is false.